# How do I get the size of a Service Broker Queue quickly when the table is >500k rows?

Tags: service-broker

I'm trying to determine the total size of a Service Broker Queue and transmission queue when the queue is very large.  The problem is traditional querys like the ones below don't work since it's not a table.  Any ideas?

```
EXEC sp_spaceused 'sys.transmission_queue'
SELECT rows FROM sysindexes WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('ConfigMgrDrsQueue') AND indid < 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remus explains explains how to do it [in his blog](http://rusanu.com/2006/11/09/fast-way-to-check-message-count/). Basically you need to query the row count of the underlying b-tree.